# Filtering duplicate records from temporary table from `regexp_split_to_table`

Tags: postgresql

I have got the following table datas.. Table name is category

```
| ID             | CATEGORY                     | 
+----------------+--------------------------+
| 1              | Apple,Orance-........... | 
| 2              | Apple,Grapes-........... | 
| 3              | Juice,Apple,Cucumber-... |
```

Im trying to create the temporary table by parsing comma seperated values as individual rows  as follows

```
| ID          | split_categori
+-------------+-------------------
| 1           | Apple
| 2           | Orange
| 3           | Grapes
| 4           | Juice
| 5           | Cucumber
```

Im using the following code to do that.

```
SELECT CATEGORI.ID, regexp_split_to_table(CATEGORI.CATEGORY, E',') AS split_categori  FROM CATEGORI;
```

`CATEGORI` is the table name. `ID` and `CATEGORY` are column names

It can successfully be able to get all comma seperated values as individual rows but then it is not filtering the duplicate elements so my new temporary table `split_categori` consists of duplicate records rows.

How can I be able to filter these duplicate records? Is there any ways to do that using query or should I rely on ResultSet?

Comment: If you have the same categori for different IDs, which ID do you want to pick? e.g. why do you have 1,Apple and not 2,Apple in the expected result?

Comment: I just want to list all comma seperated values from CATEGORY as individual rows without any duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't seem to care about the ID you pick for duplicate categories, you can use:

```
select min(c.id) as id, t.name
from categori c
  cross join regexp_split_to_table(c.category, E',') AS t(name) 
group by t.name
order by 1;
```

Note that using a set returning function in the `select` list is discouraged and should not be used any more, that's why I moved `regexp_split_to_table()` into the `from` clause.

But `regexp_split_to_table()` is an extremely slow function and should only be used if you *really* need to split on a regular expression. Using `string_to_array()` would be **much** more efficient:

```
select min(c.id) as id, t.name
from categori c
  cross join unnest(string_to_array(c.category, ',')) AS t(name) 
group by t.name
order by 1
```

Here is a running example: http://rextester.com/YSHT62551

Comment: you are a genius bro

Comment: I wish to upvote this answer thousand times for sure